# Custom routes in json-server for nested endpoint

Tags: angular, json-server

To test client's `ApiService` class I need to replace my real backend URL by a mock and for these purposes I chose **json-server**. I set up a proxy config to forward all requests that starts with `http://localhost:4200/v1/api` to `http://localhost:3000`:

```
{
    "/api/v1": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

And it works when I send requests like `http://localhost:4200/api/v1/users` **BUT** not for nested endpoints (e.g. `http://localhost:4200/api/v1/auth/token`). I found that **json-server** doesn't support requests to nested objects so I changed my **data.json** as below:

```
{
    "auth_token": {
        "access_token":"accesstoken1",
        "token_type":"Bearer"
    }
}
```

And set up **routes.json** for **json-server**:

```
{
    "/auth/token": "/auth_token"
}
```

But it doesn't work still through **json-server** uses **routes.json**:

```
[0]   Other routes
[0]   /auth/token -> /auth_token
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution didn't work due to my mistake and **json-server**'s magic:

As I found **json-server** replaces `/api/v1` to `/` automatically. But if you use routing settings above then `/api/v1/auth/token` won't be replaced to `/api/v1/auth_token` automatically and you will get **404** error.

So **json-server** behavior created an illusion for me that the proxy settings in **Angular** replaces `http://localhost:4200/api/v1` to `http://localhost:3000`. Thus the right routing in my case looks as it's shown below:

```
{
    "/api/v1/auth/token": "/api/v1/auth_token"
}
```

Comment: Quite annoying that nested routes are not supported. Then db.json will be a huge flat file without nesting, is that intentional?